# Solr: Introduce a custom field in solr query response

Tags: java, solr, customization

Is it possible to introduce *a custom field* in **Solr** `QueryResponse` that would contain a value that is computed based on another response value? For example if I have "score" field in the response, I want my custom field (let it be named "`multipliedScore`") to contain value = `(score * 10)`;

The value of the custom field needs to be calculated (not static).

Maybe there's a way to take the score value calculated by *Solr* and multiply it or turn into a string with prefix/postfix (**not** asking here about turning it into percentages)?

Comment: do you want this field to be present in the index of be generated on the fly at search time ?

Comment: the value of the filed should be generated on the fly when the search result is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using a `DocTransformer` . Just inherit from the class and implement the required logic in the `transform` method :

```
public void transform(SolrDocument doc, int docId) {
    String oldValue = doc.getFieldValue(fieldName);
    doc.put(newField,getNewValue(oldValue));
}
```